# Magento 2 How to add and call custom scss

Tags: magento2, scss

I want to know how to add scss i tried in below way in `default.xml` but it's not working

```
<css src="sass/styles.scss" />
```

How to achieve this?

Or else give me the proper way how to place and call

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this accepts SCSS files, and even if it did your browser can't render them.

What you need to do (unless you're doing something custom) is to pass it a CSS file, and compile your SCSS into CSS.

```
<css src="path/file-name.css"/>
```

Comment: I agree with @Ben. Magento 2 only supports LESS out-of-the box and it uses internal LESS-compilation to compile less to css when found. However, if you want to use SCSS, you need to setup your own stack (webpack, browsersync, gulp, whatever) and include the compiled CSS file into your document like this.